# method not calling laravel 5.1 to laravel 8.* upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

I need some clarification with dynamic controller method
i upgrading the laravel 5.1 to 8.*, all is done, but only one bug,
my url is admin/admin-profile in 5.1 is working fine, but laravel 8 is not working 404 page error is showing.
this url will call method `getAdminProfile(){ }` but is not calling.
if this functionality is not available in laravel 8, then how can i manage this, if single url i will create route, but my application have more than 100 url like this, so please help me to solve this...
i was check this issues by compare all file both laravel 5.1 and laravel 8
missing one file to capture the like this problem from ControllerInspector from routing folder.
so please help to solve this..
i can't write each method in web.php

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }

    public function getAdminProfile()
    {
        //
    }

    public function anyLogin()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like it was removed in 5.2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-is-routecontroller-deprecated has a discussion about it with some possibilities to add it back into 5.2, but the conversation is 4 years old so probably would not work with 8.

Comment: `Route::controller` doesn't exist in Laravel 8. [Available Router Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#available-router-methods). Not sure what it did, are you maybe looking for [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)?

Comment: How can access getAdminProfile by like this url  admin/admin-profile
what should do.

Comment: from my application have more than 100 url like this with different controller and method.... i can't write each method as one route.. so please give best solution for this issues

Answer (score 0):

****Resource Controller****

If `Resource Controller` can handle your need so use that:

**Documentation:** https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

and it's like below:

**Routing:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotoController;

Route::resource('photos', PhotoController::class);
```

[image]

----------------

***If Resource Controller *is not* what you want:***

you can get url and transfer `url to controller function`, for example:

**router file** `getting any url after admin\`

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{my_url?}', [AdminControlle:class, 'handle'])->where('my_url', '(.*)');
});
```

**AdminController**

```
public function handle(){
    // get url segments after admin/ - if url is like your_domain.com/admin/...
    $segments = array_slice(request()->segments(), 1);
    
   // Translate array of segments to function name - implement by you
    $functionName='';

   // calling function with knowing its name
   $functionName() // or can use call_user_func($functionName);
    
}
```

*Note: be aware that this dynamic route handling doesn't provide a solution for dynamic handling of http methods (post, get, patch, ...).

in this example i used `GET` method.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It's not working for me.... and i am using 30 controllers with more than 100 urls, i am using big application, it's not for me. i done by controller inspect class

Answer (score 0):

I just add below code in router.php

/**
* Register an array of controllers with wildcard routing.
*
* @param  array  $controllers
* @return void
*
* @deprecated since version 5.1.
*/
public function controllers(array $controllers)
{
foreach ($controllers as $uri => $controller) {
$this->controller($uri, $controller);
}
}
/**
* Prepend the last group uses onto the use clause.
*
* @param  string  $uses
* @return string
*/
protected function prependGroupUses($uses)
{
$group = end($this->groupStack);

```
    return isset($group['namespace']) && strpos($uses, '\\') !== 0 ? $group['namespace'].'\\'.$uses : $uses;
}


/**
 * Route a controller to a URI with wildcard routing.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  string  $controller
 * @param  array   $names
 * @return void
 *
 * @deprecated since version 5.1.
 */
public function controller($uri, $controller, $names = [])
{
    $prepended = $controller;

    // First, we will check to see if a controller prefix has been registered in
    // the route group. If it has, we will need to prefix it before trying to
    // reflect into the class instance and pull out the method for routing.
    if (! empty($this->groupStack)) {
        $prepended = $this->prependGroupUses($controller);
    }

    $routable = (new ControllerInspector)
                        ->getRoutable($prepended, $uri);

    // When a controller is routed using this method, we use Reflection to parse
    // out all of the routable methods for the controller, then register each
    // route explicitly for the developers, so reverse routing is possible.
   // print_r($routable);
    foreach ($routable as $method => $routes) {
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $this->registerInspected($route, $controller, $method, $names);
        }
    }

    $this->addFallthroughRoute($controller, $uri);
}

/**
 * Register an inspected controller route.
 *
 * @param  array   $route
 * @param  string  $controller
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $names
 * @return void
 *
 * @deprecated since version 5.1.
 */
protected function registerInspected($route, $controller, $method, &$names)
{
    $action = ['uses' => $controller.'@'.$method];

    // If a given controller method has been named, we will assign the name to the
    // controller action array, which provides for a short-cut to method naming
    // so you don't have to define an individual route for these controllers.
    $action['as'] = Arr::get($names, $method);

    $this->{$route['verb']}($route['uri'], $action);
}

/**
 * Add a fallthrough route for a controller.
 *
 * @param  string  $controller
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @return void
 *
 * @deprecated since version 5.1.
 */
protected function addFallthroughRoute($controller, $uri)
{
    $missing = $this->any($uri.'/{_missing}', $controller.'@missingMethod');

    $missing->where('_missing', '(.*)');
}
```

Now is working normally